# How to view statsD events in Datadog?

Tags: javascript, node.js, metrics, datadog, statsd

I am using statsD ([hot-shots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hot-shots)) to try log events in datadog such as when a new item is created and by who but, when I am calling `statsD.event('title', 'description')` I do not see any events in datadog metrics.

My statsD client is setup like this:

```
const client = new StatsD({
  port: process.env.STATSD_PORT,
  host: process.env.STATSD_HOST,
  prefix: 'service-name.',
  globalTags: {
    env: process.env.CONFIG_ENV,
    service: 'service_name'
  },
  errorHandler: error => {
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

and then I call the event method like so:

```
client.event(ACTION.CREATE, JSON.stringify({
  username: this.username,
  alias: alias,
  //...
}));
```

In the metrics section of datadog, I do not appear to be seeing any events come through. The only way I can see some logs there is using `increment`

```
client.increment(ACTION.CREATE, {
  username: this.username,
  alias: alias,
  ///...
});
```

But increment only seems to tell me how many times that action is called and I am unable to log additional data such as username and alias.

I am pretty sure my statsD client and datadog configs are setup correctly as I am able to see data from increment so I suspect it is to do with the way I am trying to use the event method.

Am I using the event method incorrectly? Perhaps I am checking in the wrong place in datadog? Perhaps I should be using increment?

How can I log events along with associated data in datadog using statsD?

Comment: Hi, did you find solution to this issue? I am facing the same.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: I was finally able to solve by explicitly opening udp port in my docker container. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67364047/not-able-to-see-metrics-on-datadog-sent-by-statsd/67854261#67854261)