# Not able to see metrics on datadog sent by statsd

Tags: datadog, statsd

I am trying to integrate statsd+datadog.

- I have launched the dd-agent container with -e
  DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC="true" , and apiKey is also correct
  (container logs confirm this)
- I am using the [official code example](https://docs.datadoghq.com/developers/metrics/dogstatsd_metrics_submission/#code-examples) to test the integration
- On datadog dashboard, in metrics explorer, I see data coming in for `datadog.dogstatsd.client.metrics`

Problem

- But not able to find the exact metrics I am pushing anywhere on datadog dashboard, how to see the metrics I pushed via statsd?
- How can I see this graph as shown from official documentation (image below)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve the problem by explicitly opening udp port of my docker container, i.e. -

```
-p 8125:8125/udp
```

full docker run command with necessary env vars and correct port binding would be

```
docker run --name dd-agent -e DD_API_KEY=<the-api-key> -e DD_SITE="datadoghq.com" -e DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC="true" -p 8125:8125/udp gcr.io/datadoghq/agent:7
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem here. I already mentioned it in a question - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645732/no-metrics-showing-on-datadog) . But not able to find where the problem lies. Since I am using Kubernetes, I already configured it on the `datadog-agent`. Completely stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here's the official doc from the console:

> **If you plan on sending custom metrics via dogstatsd** 
> By default dogstatsd will only listening to localhost, you need to add `-e DD_DOGSTATSD_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC=true` option to the container's parameters to listen to dogstatsd packets from other containers (required to send custom metrics). Then bind the container's statsd port to the hosts's IP by adding the `-p 8125:8125/udp` option to the container's parameters. Then, configure your client library to send UDP packets to the hosts's IP.

Ref: https://app.datadoghq.com/account/settings#agent/docker